# How to read the footers from the slides and store it as String

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I want to read all the footers from a ppt using python (python-pptx) and store it in different Strings. The documentation is not of much help. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    >> slide_placeholders = slide.placeholders
    >> len(slide.placeholders)
       4

    >> slide.placeholders[4]
       KeyError...
```

I was expecting to get the footer object and somehow read it.

Comment: The length is `4` so `[4]` is out of bounds... Most programming languages are `0` based so only `3, 2, 1, & 0` are valid keys for that list...

Answer (score 0):

`Slide.placeholders` returns a `_SlidePlaceholders` object, which has unusual semantics because identifying placeholders can be tricky. Used as you have above, it has `dict` semantics with the key being the value of the `idx` attribute of the placeholder. This `idx` attribute is determined by the *slide-layout* the slide was created from and which was thereby the source of its placeholder shapes. These `idx` values are essentially arbitrary and are not guaranteed to be contiguous.

You can discover the idx values like this:

```
for placeholder in slide.placeholders:
    print(placeholder.placeholder_format.idx)
```

Now the question is: "Which of these placeholders is the one I want?"

There are a few strategies:

1. **Identify by** `idx` **value:** A particular placeholder on two different slides formed from the same slide-layout will have the same `idx` value. If you can discover that `idx` value, using `slide.placeholders[idx]` is a good approach. Note that this is `dict` (key) lookup, not `list` (offset) lookup.
2. **Identify by placeholder type:** Placeholders come in different types. https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/PpPlaceholderType.html#ppplaceholdertype. If the one you want is the only one of that type on the slide, this can work

```py
 from pptx.enum.shapes import PP_PLACEHOLDER

 def find_placeholder():
     for placeholder in slide.placeholders:
         if p.placeholder_format.type == PP_PLACEHOLDER.FOOTER:
             return placeholder
     print("not found")
```

3. **Find by z-order:** This is generally not terrifically reliable because shapes can be moved forward and backward in z-order easily, but for completeness sake, say you figured yours was the last (topmost) placeholder:

```py
# ---note: this is list-semantics item access, not dict---
placeholder = list(slide.placeholders)[-1]
```